# how do I call the name of the file

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php so please forgive me. I am trying to do an image upload to the server and then upload the image name to the database so that I can call it out. However, when I try to insert the image name into the database, it tells me that the name of the file is called array. I think I am calling the file name wrongly but I have no idea what to call for the file name. My code is as follows

```
<?php
$pic=($_FILES['file']['name']); 
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {

      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      mysql_select_db($database_myconn, $myconn) or die(mysql_error()) ; 
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploads (uploade) VALUES ($pic)")  ;
      }
}

?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your form. It seams like you are using multiple file upload, so your `$_FILE` array structure is somthing like this

```
array(1) {
["upload"]=>array(5) {
    ["name"]=>array(3) {
        [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt"
        [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt"
        [2]=>string(9)"file2.txt"
    }
    ["type"]=>array(3) {
        [0]=>string(10)"text/plain"
        [1]=>string(10)"text/plain"
        [2]=>string(10)"text/plain"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>array(3) {
        [0]=>string(14)"/tmp/blablabla"
        [1]=>string(14)"/tmp/phpyzZxta"
        [2]=>string(14)"/tmp/phpn3nopO"
    }
    ["error"]=>array(3) {
        [0]=>int(0)
        [1]=>int(0)
        [2]=>int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>array(3) {
        [0]=>int(0)
        [1]=>int(0)
        [2]=>int(0)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, so if this is the case that its in an array then how can I call out the file name to insert into my database table? Thanks

Comment: So do you have multiple file upload form? If yes, do you want to save information about every file in database?
Can you run var_dump($_FILES["file"]["name"]); and add it to the question.

Comment: Ahhh its okay, I got it. I added this $pic = basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); in and now I can add the file name to the database. Thanks so much! :)